# Why Does Array<Any>.flatMap() Wrap the Transform Closure Arguments in an Optional?

Tags: arrays, swift

Below is some playground code that I am using to explore the behavior of Array's implementation of the Sequence protocol's flatMap() method. I was surprised to discover that a consequence of declaring callFlatmap's array parameter as an Array of Any is that flatMap wraps the arguments to the transform closure in an optional. Is this behavior by design?

```
func echo<T>(_ arg: T) -> T {
    print("arg = \(arg)")
    return arg
}

func callFlatten(_ array: Array<Any>) {
    print("Input: \(array)")
    print("Result: \(array.flatMap{ echo($0) })\n\n")
}

var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

callFlatten(array)
/* Prints:
     Input: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
     arg = Optional([1, 2])
     arg = Optional([3, 4])
     arg = Optional([5, 6])
     Result: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
 */

print("Input: \(array)")
print("Result: \(array.flatMap{ echo($0) })\n\n")
/* Prints:
     Input: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
     arg = [1, 2]
     arg = [3, 4]
     arg = [5, 6]
     Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
*/
```

Comment: In Swift 3.1, the call to `flatMap(_:)` inside `callFlatten` actually doesn't compile – the compiler complains that it's ambiguous (although not sure if this is intended or not)

Comment: My swift version is 3.0.2. Perhaps the behavior has been changed? It seems to me that it should be ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` has two `flatMap` methods:

```
/// Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the
/// given transformation with each element of this sequence.
public func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]
```

and

```
/// Returns an array containing the non-`nil` results of calling the given
/// transformation with each element of this sequence.
public func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

In

```
var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
// ...
print("Result: \(array.flatMap{ echo($0) })\n\n")
// Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

the first method is called, because the array element type is known
to be an array and thus a `Sequence`. `echo($0)` is called with
each element, and the result is the concatenation of the inner arrays.

In

```
func callFlatten(_ array: Array<Any>) {
    print("Input: \(array)")
    print("Result: \(array.flatMap{ echo($0) })\n\n")
}

callFlatten(array)
// Result: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

nothing is known about the element type, and the second method
is called. 
In order to match the return type `ElementOfResult?` of the closure,
the generic placeholder type of `T` of `echo` is inferred as
`Any?` and `$0` is promoted to an optional.
The result is an array with the non-nil results of `echo($0)` – which are exactly the array elements again. The type of the result is `Array<Any>`.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. The "$0 is promoted to an optional" feels odd (although I believe you). Perhaps it felt odd to others as well - what to you make of Hamish's comment?

Comment: @Verticon: Perhaps "auto-wrapped into an optional" describes it better. A function taking a `T?` parameter can always be called with a `T` argument. – I can confirm that the callFlatten method does not compile in Swift 3.1 (Xcode 8.3 beta 4), and the compiler complains about ambiguity between those two flatMap methods which I listed. It *seems* like a bug to me, because only one of them can be applied.

Comment: Are you saying that echo(arg: Any?) satisfies the (Element) declaration of flatMap's transform parameter?

Comment: @Verticon: What I mean is that when `echo` is called from within `callFlatten`, `T` is `Any?`.